# CommonOpenFileDialog allows usage of parent window

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello my application uses some `OpenFileDialog`s for file picking. Furthermore, I need a folder picker for which I used the `CommonOpenFileDialog` with the option `IsFolderPicker = true`.

Now when I open an `OpenFileDialog` in the app the parent window is locked and can't be used anymore, exactly the behavior I want.
But when I use the `CommonOpenFileDialog` I can still access the parent window and open even more `CommonOpenFileDialog`s.

The `OpenFileDialog` is intialized like this:

```
//init dialog
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(SecondQPcrFilePath);
openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
openFileDialog.CheckPathExists = true;
openFileDialog.Multiselect = false;
openFileDialog.ReadOnlyChecked = false;
openFileDialog.ShowReadOnly = false;

//show dialog
bool? dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
```

The `CommonOpenFileDialog` like this:

```
//is this mvvm conform?
Button senderButton = (Button)sender;
string clickedButton = senderButton.Name;
//init dialog
CommonOpenFileDialog openPathDialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();

openPathDialog.IsFolderPicker = true;
openPathDialog.EnsurePathExists= true;
openPathDialog.Multiselect = false;
openPathDialog.EnsureFileExists = false;
openPathDialog.AllowNonFileSystemItems = true;

if(clickedButton == "limsOpenButton")
{
    openPathDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(LimsPath);
}
else if(clickedButton == "qpcrOpenButton")
{
    openPathDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(QpcrPath);
}
//show dialog
CommonFileDialogResult dialogResult = openPathDialog.ShowDialog();
```

Is there a way to prevent that behavior? The common dialog does not have a property like `Owner` or similiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common file dialog exposes an overload for the `ShowDialog` method.

```
public CommonFileDialogResult ShowDialog(Window window);
```

Pass the parent window to this method and the dialog will be modal.

```
var window = // Get the parent window here.
var dialogResult = openPathDialog.ShowDialog(window);
```

It looks like you use code-behind, so `this` would be the window. Alternatively you could use `MainWindow` or the `Windows` collection in `Application.Current` to find the window.